# Is Android's FragmentTransaction.commit() Method Thread Safe?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm just curious about whether or not I have to call this on the UI-Thread or not. According to the documentation, the `commit` is run on the UI-thread further on in the future, when it has time to do so. If this is the case, can I run `FragmentTransaction.commit()` on another thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you mean. You may always have any other thread which sends a message to the UI thread invoking FragmentTransaction.commit().

However, I do not quite understand why you do not call commit immediately after all the transactions.

I would even expect that you may even experience NullPointer Errors should there have been any changed to the fragments or their depending data - during the delay I mean - which cause a different state of your app than when you would call commit immediately.

Also in that context you should call `fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()` to ensure that all your changes will be made, otherwise you may assume that the transactions have taken place - which in fact they haven't yet.

Comment: I'm using Facebook's SDK, and one of its callbacks occurs in a separate thread. I was wondering if I could still show a `ProgressDialog` or `AlertDialog` from the callback, or if I'd have to send the request to the UI-thread.

Comment: I am not familiar with Facebook SDK, however, you need to be careful when using fragments that might disappear (like ProgressDialog and AlertDialog). You need to ensure that all the methods in other objects that rely upon these fragments get informed in case these fragments are gone. eg simply by the user pressing "back". But you may create these fragments from anywhere you like, since you have to put them in/attach them to your UI activity anyways

Answer (score 16):

This question is a year old but I wanted to address it because I suspect it's an issue that a lot of people will encounter.

Working with FragmentTransactions, including calling the commit method, *is safe to do on non-UI threads* because none of the work that occurs within the FragmentTransaction directly manipulates the UI. The method calls on the FragmentTransaction are simply packaged up as a list of instructions of work to be performed.

Once you call the commit method, that package of instructions is then sent over to the UI thread for processing.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone needs the most updated answer in 2023 like me, **IT IS THREAD-SAFE**.

As the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction?hl=en#commit()) says:

> The commit does not happen immediately; it will be scheduled as work on the main thread to be done the next time that thread is ready.

I tried in my own code to commit a fragment transaction in a non-UI thread and it worked without a crash.